# Does this property hold for the Jordan form of a Matrix?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, jordan-normal-form

Suppose $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of the matrix $M$ with geometric multiplicity $r$.

I have the feeling that in the Jordan form of $M$, there are $r$ columns that contains only $\lambda$ (and no $1$) (there may be other columns that contain $\lambda$ but will also have $1$). Is this true?

Answer (score 1):

Let $\pmb{M} \in \mathbb{C}^{N \times N}$ be a matrix. There exists an invertible matrix $\pmb{P}$ such that $\pmb{J }= \pmb{P}^{-1}\pmb{M}\pmb{P}$, under the following block diagonal form 
\begin{equation}
\pmb{J}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
\pmb{J}_1 &  &   & \\
     & \pmb{J}_2 &   & \\
& & \ddots   &  \\
     & &        & \pmb{J}_p\\
\end{bmatrix}
\in
\mathbb{C}^{N\times N}
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
\pmb{J}_k
=
\begin{bmatrix}
\lambda_k &  1&   & &\\
     & \lambda_k & 1  & &\\
& & \ddots   & \ddots &\\
     & &       & \lambda_k &1\\
     & &        & & \lambda_k\\
\end{bmatrix}
\in
\mathbb{C}^{N_k\times N_k}
\end{equation}
where $\lambda_k$ is an eigenvalue of multiplicity $N_k$ $(\sum\limits_{k=1}^p N_k = N)$

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is true. In the Jordan form of $M$, there will be precisely $r$ blocks associated to the eigenvalue $\lambda$. In each such block, there will be precisely one column (the first, by usual conventions) that contains $\lambda$ and only $\lambda$ and all other columns in the block will also contain a $1$.